# Getting Android+Gradle+Jenkins+Spoon to work together

Tags: java, android, jenkins, spoon

I am trying to get Android, Gradle, Jenkins and Spoon to work together.

1. I am building an Android app.
2. I have jenkins setup.
3. I have gradle plugin installed.
4. I have these gradle script commands:
   a. --stacktrace --debug clean assembleDebug assembleDebugAndroidTest
   b. --stacktrace --debug cleanTest assembleDebugAndroidTest installDebugAndroidTest
5. I am trying to run the android tests on a device via spoon:
   java -jar C:\spoon\spoon-runner-1.1.10-jar-with-dependencies.jar --apk app.apk --test-apk test.apk
6. When I run these tests, it seems like it's running, and it spits out output into spoon-output, but it doesn't actually run the tests, I get: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

If I build from android studio and run these tests manually, it works as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with bonnyz, use spoon plugin. I got it working with multidex.

Here is my build.config

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {

            mavenCentral()
                /** Ommited project specific config **/

        }


        dependencies {
            classpath 'de.felixschulze.gradle:gradle-spoon-plugin:2.7.3'
        }
    }


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'de.felixschulze.gradle.spoon'

    repositories {
                /** Ommited project specific config **/

        maven { url "htt/jitpack.io" }

        flatDir{
            dirs 'libs'
        }

    }



    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    //        exclude 'NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'NOTICE'

        }

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23

            multiDexEnabled = true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


        }


        /*
        Creating flavours. Local is the basic dev mode. QA is built for testing, distributing to QA. Production is the final version
        For Local the crashlytics is disabled. For QA and Production, crashlytics is enabled.
        */
        //Optimizing Multidex Development Builds
        // Dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
        // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
        // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
        // For more info https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#dev-build
        productFlavors {
            QA {
                // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
                minSdkVersion 14
            }

            Production {
                // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
                minSdkVersion 14
            }

            Local {
                //Optimizing Multidex Development Builds https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#dev-build
                minSdkVersion 21
            }

        }


        signingConfigs {
            /**
             * Uncomment this when you are doing a release build. Make sure you set Env Vars
             */
            release {
                        /** Ommited project specific config **/

            }

            debug {
                        /** Ommited project specific config **/

            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles  'proguard-rules.pro'
                /**
                 * Uncomment this when you are doing a release build.
                 */

                /** Ommited project specific config **/


            }

            debug {
                        /** Ommited project specific config **/


            }
        }



        dexOptions {
            jumboMode true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            incremental true
        }
    }


    spoon {
        debug = true
        failOnFailure = true
        adbTimeout = 2 * 60
        failIfNoDeviceConnected = true
    }

    project.getConfigurations().all { config ->
        if (config.name.contains("AndroidTest")) {
            config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.name == "multidex") {
                    details.useTarget("de.felixschulze.teamcity:teamcity-status-message-helper:1.2")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {

        /** Ommited other dependencies **/
        provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        /** *** Google libraries   *****/
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.4.2@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        compile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-runner:1.3.1'

        debugCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.+'
        debugCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.+'
        debugCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
        debugCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
        // Instrumentation testing dependencies
        compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
        // Unit testing dependencies
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        // Memory leak testing dependencies
        debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
        releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
        // Dependency injection
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
        apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
        provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
        androidTestApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
        // Third party libraries

        androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.3.1'
        // Crashlytics Kit

        android {
            lintOptions {
                abortOnError false
            }
        }

    }


    configurations {
        androidTestCompile.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        androidTestCompile.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }



    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    }
```

Run the tests by

```
gradle clean connectedQADebugAndroidTest
```

This will run all the tests with QADebug flavor.

For spoon plugin, I used https://github.com/x2on/gradle-spoon-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use the [Spoon Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin) directly.

From the official docs:

### Setup

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'spoon'

// This section is optional
spoon {
  // for debug output
  debug = true

  // To run a single test class
  className = 'fully.qualified.TestCase'

  // To run a single method in TestCase
  methodName = 'testMyApp'
}
```

### Run

```
./gradlew spoon
```